# How many wars did the Prophet (SAW) lead?

Tags: jihad, history, war, prophet-muhammad

During the time of the Prophet (SAW) government in Medina, how many wars did he lead?

I have heard that the Prophet (SAW) was involved in more than 100 wars. Are these statistics correct? What is real number of them?

Comment: What do you mean by "manage"? Lead the battle himself? There are several battles that result from armies being sent by the prophet but led by other people (i.e. battle of Mu'tah).

Comment: @SystemDown yes I mean lead himself. in some wars prophet was not fighting inside battlefield but leaded war.

Comment: what is a "peaceful conflict" in the context of the question? Just a disagreement?

Comment: How do you define a war? Do you mean how many battles? How to count wars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a complete list with all the details in this Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_expeditions_of_Muhammad).

According to this source, nabi Muhammad did 100 expeditions, and 27 of them were wars and conflicts.

Comment: thanks there are 100 wars there. I think the correct number is something around 100.

Comment: But not all of them are wars. Some are only expeditions which concluded without any conflict.

Comment: -1 this does not answer the question. It is just a link to a Wikipedia page that doesn't show all wars, since not all wars were expeditions.

Comment: Agreed with Dynamic. Please also cite the relevant part of the source in your answer.

Comment: @ashes999 OK, I did so.

Comment: This is a link of wikipedia. You should use a trusted sources.

Answer (score 3):

The meaning fatwa in this [webpage](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=4463).

Zaid was asked how many Ghazwa (غزوة) did the prophet Muhammad  صلى الله عليه وسلم  have? He answered 19, then He was asked about the number of times that he was with the prophet Muhammad صلى الله عليه وسلم. He said 17.

And Ahl al seer اهل السير said that it was 25, and some people said 27, and some people said 29.

And al-Hafiz(الحافظ) ibn Hajr said after he collected these says, the people that mentioned a high number take each event of these as a Ghazwa, but people who mentioned less take the events that are happened in the same period of time is one Ghazwa for example taking bani Qurayza(بني قريظة), al-Khandaq(الخندق) as one Gazwa. And Sarayas(سرايا) were more, they are from 40-70

Answer (score 0):

During the time of the Prophet (S) government in Medina, Prophet Muhammad (Peace Be Upon Him), himself participated in 28 wars which are called Ghuzwa, and sent troops 54 times for different wars making someone else as a commander. These 54 wars are called Sareea and Prophet Muhammad (Peace Be Upon Him) did not participate in them.

So altogether there are 82 wars during the time of the Prophet (S) government in Medina

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE. Generally, answers should be backed with proofs of some sort. Please cite yours in your answer.